# Capture Image using Jquery without Flash Object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, flash, image-capture

I was working on capturing image using jquery in ASP.NET MVC3, I found some articles related to it and used

```
scriptcam.js
```

which uses flash object for creating window to capture image.

I want to make the exact same application but without having any role of ADOBE FLASH in it.

Comment: Most browsers don't support this yet because it's still a specification under development: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little uncertain as to what you're trying to capture. If you're trying to save a screenshot of the browser you can put what you want to capture into an html canvas tag and then save out the file by using the data URI. A great example can be found here: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

If you need help capturing the page in a canvas element you can use html2canvas:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: No I am going to capture live picture from webcam

Comment: As long as your webcam is being drawn on a canvas element canvas2image will still work for you.